# Python 3: Parse Server message(TCP)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, parsing, tcpclient

I wrote a client using the socket module and now I am trying to decode a message I receive from an external TCP Server with the following Code(I know the Package has an 8 byte long header with details such as size in the first 2 bytes. After the Header there is an error message, which I am trying to decode):

```
received = sock.recv(1024)
print ("Bytes Received: {}".format(received.decode()))
```

When doing this I get the following error message:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 0: invalid continuation byte

When I try to exclude the header by using:

```
print ("Bytes Received: {}".format(received[9:].decode()))
```

I just get an empty result:

```
Bytes Received:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to decode a '\x00' byte, for example:

```
>>> print('Output: ' + b'\x00'.decode())
Output: 
>>>
```

Anyway, if it is long 8 bytes (UDP header is formed by 8 bytes, not TCP) you should write:

```
print ("Bytes Received: {}".format(received[8:].decode()))
```

If you want to work with TCP packets i suggest you to use a packet manipulator like Scapy: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html